# If I handle a GUI on a single thread that is not the EDT, is it still thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, event-dispatch-thread

If I create a GUI on a different thread, and make sure that any updates that happen to the GUI occur on that thread and that thread only- is it then still thread safe? I know this would be difficult to ensure, so in a way I'm kind of asking: Is there anything special/different about the EDT compared to other threads?

Keep in mind I'm not asking about good practices or other solutions to this problem, I'm asking if, on a purely technical level, if you basically treated a thread like the EDT, would the GUI created on the new thread be safe to use?

Comment: If the user clicks the mouse on your GUI, on which thread will the MouseEvent be delivered to MouseListeners?

Comment: I'll presume it always gets delivered to the EDT. I wish they mentioned these things in college. I had a particularly brutal lecturer for my concurrency module... So, to clarify, are certain events *always* done on the EDT, with no control over it..? Sorry if these are stupid questions btw.

Comment: Correct.  The Event Dispatch Thread is under the control of the AWT system.  The creation of Java events based on native input is done internally and they are sent to that thread.

Answer (score 1):

It is not thread safe because your processes are not the only one that read/write UI element. JRE is also read and write but it does it via EDT. So even if you read/write in the single thread which is not EDT there are processes that do it in EDT - so you end up with one UI element, few threads, no synchronization.